# Can I send message to the "Junk Email" folder using Exchange based off a header?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013, outlook-2010

Is there a way using Exchange to send messages with a specific header like (X-Junk-Mail: ) to the "Junk Email" folder without having to create rules in the client?  I'd like to have borderline spam messages tagged as such in a header through our SPAM filter and have it placed in a user's "Junk Email" folder.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely, use Spam Confidence Level, for example, dmarc/spf failures are marked as SCL 9 instead of rejecting in o365

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995744(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: What about with on prem exchange 2013?

Comment: X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL:5 https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aa997692(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: I updated the link, there's little difference between hosted and prem 2013.

Comment: Does this require the anti-spam agent?

Comment: You can just set that header in a hub transport role